winlib-imagex will not merge files
I have just installed wimlibtools, i'm trying to merge 3 split swm files using winlib-imagex.
when i type wimlib-imagex join /home/yikes/Desktop/win10work/sources/install.swm /home/yikes/Desktop/win10work/sources/merged_install.wim

i get the following error:  [ERROR] Can't open "/home/yikes/Desktop/win10work/sources/merged_install.wim" read-only: No such file or directory
ERROR: Exiting with error code 47:
Failed to open a file. ** 
I've tried working in a different folder and i still get the same error.
anyone have any tips?

ok i've come to a point where i just have to ask in basic English, can i create a modified bootable windows 10 iso file in Ubuntu. ? simple yes or no?

From the Ubuntu wimjoin manual page:
wimlib-imagex join [OPTION...] OUT_WIMFILE SPLIT_WIM_PART


wimjoin,  or  equivalently wimlib-imagex join, joins the
SPLIT_WIM_PARTs into a standalone
(one-part) WIM OUT_WIMFILE.  All parts of the split WIM must be  specified;  you  probably
want to do so using a shell wildcard.

This is an example:
 wimjoin windows.wim windows*.swm

In your case use this command:
wimjoin /home/yikes/Desktop/win10work/sources/merged_install.wim /home/yikes/Desktop/win10work/sources/install*.swm 


hi Talaat Elman. Thank you for replying. wimjoin works, I'm a step closer now. Thanks a million bud!]
